# Metaballs are different colors in sculpt mode

Tags: sculpting

I created a few metaballs and used boolean to combine them with another mesh.

[image]

The dark purple is what were the metaballs. They are one object, but a different color from the fingers I connected to them. Already checked the normals, they're all flipped outside. And there are no materials.

Comment: Maybe it's a face sets color? Try header menu > Face Sets > Init Face Sets > By Loose Parts.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Your solution worked @moonbots, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, try turning on (Dyntopo) it worked for me.

.[image: screenshot]